# TinyMCE 5 Getting rid of ghost table borders

Tags: tinymce, border

Getting rid of ghost table borders (shows dotted)
I still get a ghost/transparent border around the table/cell and in between rows. Is there any way to get rid of this in TinyMCE ?
I need to be able to generate a table without any lines, even the faintest one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyMCE by default adds a dotted border around borderless tables. To remove them, add the option `visual: false` [as described here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#visual)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS (via `content_css` or `content_style`) to remove the guidelines that TinyMCE places in the editor for the content author.

I would note that doing this will make it very difficult for the content author to realize that (a) they are in a table and (b) where the table, cells, and rows start or end.

If you really want to do this here is an example of the CSS that would address this:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Yrhaab

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Michael,

Is there also a way to hide only the borders without a border attribute ?

We use TinyMCE to answer on e-mails, and it looks very ugly, if these e-mails using tables.
But some table formattings with borders should be displayed. Only the borders without any style should be hidden.

Armin